# nodeJS - findOne query did not cast into JSON object even query result was good

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

findOne was able to find document in MongoDB.  However, the result was not rendered into JSON object employeeLs.  Findone result was printed in console and it was clear that query returned good result.

I am new to Angular, NodeJS and MongoDB.  Many hours have been spent on researching this issue and could not resolve this "strange" issue. "strange" because findOne was initiated by "employeeLs." and expected result to be directly passed to object employeeLs.  Besides, it was a straight ask of all fields for employeeLs. Any help is appreciated.

Below pls find coding info.

**route coding**

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
//const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const { Console } = require('console');
const mongooseClient = require('mongoose');  /* this is important  */
var employeeLs = require('../model/staffLeave');
const staffLeaveRouter = express.Router();
const util = require('util');
staffLeaveRouter.use(bodyParser.json());
staffLeaveRouter.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

staffLeaveRouter.route('/:staff_id')
.get((req,res,next) => {
    employeeLs.findOne({staff_id : req.params.staff_id}) 
    .populate(staffRecords._id)
    .then(result => { 
        console.log(result);  
        console.log('lllll - inside retreival by staffid',JSON.stringify(util.inspect(employeeLs,{showHidden:false,depth:5})));
        /* console.dir(employeeLs,this.options); */
        employeeLs : result;
                  }
      )
    .then((employeeLs) => {
        if (employeeLs != null) 
           {res.statusCode = 200;
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            res.json(employeeLs)}
        else{
            err = new Error('Staffleave using staff ID to find '+req.params.staff_id+' not found');
            err.status = 404;
            return next(err);
        }
        
    }, (err) => next(err))
    .catch((err) => next(err));
})
```

**Schema coding**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
require('mongoose-currency').loadType(mongoose);
const Currency = mongoose.Types.Currency;

const staffLeaveSchema = new Schema({
    _id: {type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, required: true},
    staff_id: {type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, required: true,
               ref: 'staffRecord'},
    staffUsername: {type: String, required: true},   
    year: {type: Number, required: true},
    annualLeaveEntitlement: {type: Number, required: true},
    carryOver: {type: Number, required: true},
    thisYearTotalAllowed: {type: Number, required: true},
    taken: {type: Number, required: false},
    scheduled: {type: Number, required: false},
    thisYearRemaing: {type: Number, required: false},
    sickLeaveTaken: {type: Number, required: false},
    maternityLeaveTaken: {type: Number, required: false},
    noPayLeaveTaken: {type: Number, required: false},
    familyLeaveTaken: {type: Number, required: false},
});

var staffLeave = mongoose.model('staffLeave', staffLeaveSchema);
module.exports = staffLeave;
```

From console log, **findone result returned** as below.  However, system still said employeeLs was still null.  It was not rendered as expected.

```
{
  _id: 5f069b7821233471ec530b80,
  staff_id: 5edfd3bf07cc253f1065de24,
  staffUsername: 'dwong',
  year: 2020,
  annualLeaveEntitlement: 10,
  carryOver: 2,
  thisYearTotalAllowed: 12,
  taken: 0,
  scheduled: 0,
  thisYearRemaing: 12,
  sickLeaveTaken: 0,
  maternityLeaveTaken: 0,
  noPayLeaveTaken: 0,
  familyLeaveTaken: 0,
  __v: 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont really understand what this code bellow want achieve :

```
.then(result => { 
        console.log(result);  
        console.log('lllll - inside retreival by staffid',JSON.stringify(util.inspect(employeeLs,{showHidden:false,depth:5})));
        /* console.dir(employeeLs,this.options); */
        employeeLs : result;
                  }
      )
```

do you want the next(second) .then to get the result  from first .then ?
if yes

```
.then(result => { return result })
.then((employeeLs) => {
        if (employeeLs != null) 
           {res.statusCode = 200;
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            res.json(employeeLs)}
        else{
            err = new Error('Staffleave using staff ID to find '+req.params.staff_id+' not found');
            err.status = 404;
            return next(err);
        }
        
})
```

Let me expect what do you want achieve, do you want fetch a document with mongoose and send it as response json?
I think you just need something like this

```
staffLeaveRouter.route('/:staff_id')
.get((req,res,next) => {
    employeeLs.findOne({staff_id : req.params.staff_id}) 
    .populate(staffRecords._id)
    .then(result => {
      if (result) {
        res.status(200).send({data : result}) 
      } else {
        res.status(204).end()
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
       console.log(err)
       res.status(500).send({ err : "error" })
    })
})
```

Comment: Hokdre, thanks for your prompt and great assistance.  Objective was to fetch data from mongoDB and give it to object employeeLs to be used by Angular code. Reason for my first code of "result" was to see if findOne worked.  Reason to said "employeeLs = result" was to try to get data for employeeLs as system always said it was null.  I followed your first suggestion and system performed what was expected.  Presumed different way of coding "return" statement had its impact.  I will do more research to understand that.  With much appreciation.

Comment: nice to hear it works for you, i think good to read about how js handle async process like promise chaining and async await